# Why adding a Paragraph to a Paragraph modify leading of outer Paragraph?

Tags: java, itext

I have a question about the leading of Paragraph object in Itext (I'm using version 5.2.1).
This is the code:

```
BaseFont f = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font ftext = new Font(f, 12);
Paragraph ptest = new Paragraph("Line n.1\nLine n.2\nLine n.3", ftext);
Paragraph pInner = new Paragraph("This has\nleading=28", ftext);
pInner.setLeading(28f);
ptest.add(pInner);
ptest.add(new Chunk("Line n.4 (chunk)\n"));
ptest.add(new Chunk("Line n.5 (chunk)\n"));
ptest.add(new Chunk("Line n.6 (chunk)\n"));
ptest.add(new Chunk("Outer paragraph leading=" + ptest.getLeading()));
document.add(ptest);
```

The resulting PDF from this code is not what I'm expecting.

The outer Paragraph, **ptest**, has leading 18 (calculated by iText multiplying font size by 1.5); then I add a second Paragraph **pInner**, with leading 28 and finally I add **to the first Paragraph** four chunks.
Since **ptest** has still leading 18, I'd expect that the last 4 lines would have a leading = 18, instead have a leading = 28.

Is this correct or the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not expected behaviour.

We have improved leading processing.  It will be available in the upcoming 5.4.5 release.